# Commutative associative rational binary operations

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, abstract-algebra, universal-algebra

What are all the nondegenerate rational binary operations that are commutative and associative?  (Examples: $(x,y) \mapsto x+y$, $xy+x+y$, $xy/(x+y)$.)

Feel free to re-tag if you can think of something better than "algebra".

Clarification: I intended that $x$ and $y$ denote complex numbers; that the operations be defined almost everywhere; and that the functions not be constant.

Comment: What are $x,y$?

Comment: I am suggesting an edit that includes the phrase "real numbers".

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger: If these are real numbers, then apply the third operation of the question to $x=y=0$ or $x=5, y=-5$.

Comment: James, what do you mean by "nondegenerate operation"? I assume it is a kind of partial function...

Comment: Indeed Mark, I hope clarity ensues.  Given what I have seen from this poster, phrases like "with domain restricted appropriately" don't appear on the first pass.

Comment: I think all that is meant is that formal equations are satisfied: we have a rational function in two variables $f(x, y)$ such that $f(f(x, y), z) = f(x, f(y, z))$ in the field of rational functions on three variables, and $f(x, y) = f(y, x)$. Nondegenerate might include nonconstant.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: Rational functions over what field (ring)? What does $f(f(x,y),z)=f(x,f(y,z))$ mean? For example, is $x^2/x$ equal $x$? I voted to close the question.

Comment: @MarkSapir Well, the coefficient ring should be clarified; I would take $\mathbb{C}$ as my default. Yes, $x^2/x = x$, if we interpret in the field of rational functions. One bunch of examples is to take $f(x, y) = \phi^{-1}(\phi(x) + \phi(y))$ or $f(x, y) = \phi^{-1}(\phi(x)\phi(y))$ where $\phi$ is an automorphism on the field of rational functions $\mathbb{C}(x)$ in one variable (linear fractional transformation). But I agree it would be nice to have James Propp confirm.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear in my earlier comment, "rational *function*" might be a misleading (although standard) term. The point was to avoid discussion of set-theoretic *functions*, and interpret a rational "function" purely formally as an element of the field of fractions of the ring of polynomials. I think thinking of actual functions and their domains is distracting us from what the OP intends, which is really a purely formal problem (and one of potential interest). At least, I *think* that's what he intends.

Comment: @ToddTrimble:  Yes,this would be a meaningful interpretation.

Comment: Jim, are you already familiar with formal groups http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_group ? That's pretty close to what you're asking for.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger Given what I have seen from this poster's body of research work, I am inclined to persevere rather than dismiss

Comment: No disrespect intended to James Propp. I too would persevere. Thus the suggested edit and the expressed hope for clarity.  Like many other posters here, James "does not nail it the first time".  That's all.

Comment: One lesson I have learned from this exchange is to check replies periodically after posting (every few hours), rather than 12 hours later; that way, I can give clarifications quickly, before people have had to make lots of surmises about the OP's intended meaning, and frustration starts to build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many examples of such operations can be constructed as follows.

Let $F$ be a meromorphic function which has a rational addition theorem.
This means that $F(u+v)=R(F(u),F(v))$ for all (complex) $u$ and $v$, where $R$ is a
rational function. Then $R$ gives you a rational commutative associative operation.

All such meromorphic functions $F$ have been classified. There is a theorem of
Weierstrass that every such $F$ is either rational, or a rational function of $\exp(au)$,
or an elliptic function. This gives plenty of examples of operations.
For example, taking $F(u)=\tan u$ gives operation $(x+y)/(1-xy)$.

In the case of elliptic functions, you can even obtain 1-parametric families of
such operations.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of picture I was hoping for. Is a more explicit description of such functions $R$ available?  Also, which such $R$'s are homogeneous?

Comment: A special case of this answer (which seems to cover the examples in your question) is the theory of Formal Groups. That theory has been very well developed, and in that case the function $R$ is the log function. If you google you'll find tons of survey articles. There's very little machinery needed: just power series

Comment: Perhaps a more complete answer can be found in the work of J. F. Ritt, but I do not remember the exact reference at this moment. BTW he also created the theory of formal groups.

Comment: For a follow-up question, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/139331/generalizing-detropicalization .